# grid-area css not working on chrome correctly

Tags: html, css

I have a issue with grid area and chrome it doesn't work correctly like on firefox.
anyone have a solution?

I didn't fine any answer, normaly we must see 5lines et 2 columns but with chrome the first line jump on the second line and not in firexfox and edge...

https://codepen.io/tagline2020/pen/qBNNzYQ

'''

```
<div class="page-width-grid-10">
  <div class="product-1"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/luxury-letter-e-logo-design_1017-8903.jpg"/></div>
  <div class="product-2"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/luxury-letter-e-logo-design_1017-8903.jpg"/></div>
  <div class="product-3"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/luxury-letter-e-logo-design_1017-8903.jpg"/></div>
  <div class="product-4"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/luxury-letter-e-logo-design_1017-8903.jpg"/></div>
  <div class="product-5"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/luxury-letter-e-logo-design_1017-8903.jpg"/></div>
  <div class="product-6"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/luxury-letter-e-logo-design_1017-8903.jpg"/></div>
  <div class="product-7"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/luxury-letter-e-logo-design_1017-8903.jpg"/></div>
  <div class="product-8"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/luxury-letter-e-logo-design_1017-8903.jpg"/></div>
  <div class="product-9"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/luxury-letter-e-logo-design_1017-8903.jpg"/></div>
  <div class="product-10"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/luxury-letter-e-logo-design_1017-8903.jpg"/></div>
</div>
```

'''

'''

```
.page-width-grid-10{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 20% 20% 20% 20%;
  grid-template-rows: 20% 20% 20% 20% 20%;
  grid-template-areas: 
  "product-1 product-2 product-3 product-4 product-5"
  "product-6 product-7 product-8 product-9 product-10";
  margin-left: 8%;
  margin-right: 8%;
  
}

.page-width-grid-10 img{
  width: 100%;
}

.product-1{
  grid-area: product-1;
  border: #d4b26b solid 1px;
}
.product-2{
  grid-area: product-2;
  border: #d4b26b solid 1px;
}
.product-3{
  grid-area: product-3;
  border: #d4b26b solid 1px;
}
.product-4{
  grid-area: product-4;
  border: #d4b26b solid 1px;
}
.product-5{
  grid-area: product-5;
  border: #d4b26b solid 1px;
}
.product-6{
  grid-area: product-6;
  border: #d4b26b solid 1px;
}
.product-7{
  grid-area: product-7;
  border: #d4b26b solid 1px;
}
.product-8{
  grid-area: product-8;
  border: #d4b26b solid 1px;
}
.product-9{
  grid-area: product-9;
  border: #d4b26b solid 1px;
}.product-10{
  grid-area: product-10;
  border: #d4b26b solid 1px;
}
```

'''

Comment: `grid-template-rows: 20% 20% 20% 20% 20%;` <-- you want two lines so why defining 5?

Comment: this is a mistake but the problem remains the same if I put only 2, what would you have put? thx

Comment: well, don't put anything, simply remove it

Comment: :) oh great is working! thank you :)

Comment: i don't understand why in this video it s working perfectly...https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EFafSYg-PkI but thank you